# Write Once, Test Everywhere - Selenium and Python's unittest on desktop and mobile

Tags: python, selenium, cross-browser, cross-platform, python-unittest

I'm working with Selenium and Python's unittest and I'm creating test cases for desktop, tablet and mobile websites. However, it's not ideal to have three test cases that test on same things.

At the moment, I put `self.driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)` in the desktop's test method and `self.driver.set_window_size(414, 736)` in the mobile's test method. So I have two test methods that do the same job mostly.

I am looking for some ways to encapsulate the `set_window_size()` and to have one test method, maybe with the `if` loop to test on some elements that may only appear on mobile or desktop websites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor to place common code into a separate method.

```
class Mytest(unittest.TestCase):

    def do_test(self):
        # your actual test code

    def test_something_mobile(self):
        self.driver.set_window_size(1366, 768)
        self.do_test()

    def test_something_mobile(self):
        self.driver.set_window_size(414, 768)
        self.do_test()
```

the above code assumes that the driver is initialized elsewhere typically done in `__init__`

Answer (score 0):

With a solution from e4c5, I was able to run one test case on desktop and mobile.

I would need to have a if loop to test an element that may be on mobile but not on desktop and vice versa.

So my solution was:

```
if self.driver.get_window_size() == {'height': 736, 'width': 414}:
```